# Rsync keeps copying the same file

Tags: filesystem, rsync, utf-8

I have used **rsync** for many years between linux filesystems without any problem with a very deterministic behavior. Now I try to use it on mac and experience some problem that some files (a small proportion of my 600000 files) gets copied over and over.

Here is what I tried:

1. Moving from MacOS rsync 2.6.9 to rsync 3.1.3 (from brew) did not solve the problem.
2. Giving some large time interval in order to avoid possible clock skew did not resolve the problem.
3. I saw in some other answers that a possible problem is the *utf-8* vs *utf-8-mac* characters. I understand that it can be a problem but I am ready to accept ascii filenames for the purpose of having linux and mac coexisting. The files in question have ASCII file names.

The weird think about it is that this unexpected behavior is completely deterministic. The same file **ListDebug/ForDEBUG** gets copied over and over. Yet the file **ListDebug/ForDEBUG2** which is next to it was not copied over and over.

Any indication on the origin of this strange behavior would be much welcomed.

EDIT: I found some more info when copying only the directory **ListDebug**.
When I run **rsync -vadi -e ssh remote:ListDebug .** I get

```
mathieu@MacBook-Pro: rsync -vadi -e ssh remote:ListDebug .
>f.st......... ListDebug/ForDebug
mathieu@MacBook-Pro: rsync -vadi -e ssh remote:ListDebug .
>f.st......... ListDebug/ForDEBUG
mathieu@MacBook-Pro: rsync -vadi -e ssh remote:ListDebug .
>f.st......... ListDebug/ForDebug
```

Thus there is some oscillation between one print and another. That really sounds strange and a bug.

EDIT2: The file **ListDebug/ForDebug** gets copied but become named **ListDebug/ForDEBUG** and the file **ForDEBUG** never gets copied.

EDIT3: If I change the content of `ForDebug/ForDEBUG` to something standard like `TEST1`, `TEST2` then the bug remains. On the other hand if I rename the files `ForDebug/ForDEBUG` to `file1/file2` then the bug disappear. Ve

Comment: This is not a problem I generally see with rsync on Mac at all. Just to be sure - the file "ForDEBUG" that is transferre over and over - does its contents change at all? (i.e. do you have some program that has the file open?) - Does the timestamp on it change?

Comment: Try an rsync of just this one file and use `-i` to list the reason for the transfer. If that is not helpful, there is `--debug=all4` which is very verbose, so best done on one file only.

Comment: You might want to check to make sure that both file systems are set to use the same level of case-sensitivity (i.e. both are case-sensitive, or both are case-insensitive).

Comment: `s` means the size is different, and `t` that the time differs. But I dont know why the filename changes from `ForDebug` to `ForDEBUG` each time. Try `ls -i ListDebug/For*` before the rsync to see if the inode number is changing too.

Comment: Might be an issue with the file itself then. Do size/timestamp actually change (run `ls -l ForDebug` before and after `rsync` to check)? Is the file actively being updated whily `rsync` is running? Has it any permissions/ACLs/extended attributes set differently than other files? If it is a text file, can you run `cat ForDEBUG > foo; rm ForDEBUG; mv foo ForDEBUG` and try again?

Comment: So, I did a `cat` operation, `rm` and `mv` for both files `ForDebug` and `ForDEBUG` and the result was the same: The file `ForDebug` was copied on the mac in the file `ForDEBUG`. If I change the content of `ForDebug` and `ForDEBUG` to something mondane like `TEST1` , `TEST2` then the behavior remains. If on the other I rename `ForDebug/ForDEBUG` to `file1/file2` then the bug disappear.

Comment: Then surely the problem is, as mentioned above by @user128998,  that the destination filesystem is case-insensitive, whilst the remote is case-sensitive.

Comment: Mathieu, wait, why do you mention two files (`ForDebug` and `ForDEBUG`)? Do you have both on the source system? If yes, do you also have `ForDebug2`and `ForDEBUG2`?

Comment: Apparently @user128998 was correct. The system is case-insensitive, something I could not have imagined.

Comment: So, how could we change the filesystem to a case sensitive one? I know it is a different question, but `diskutil info /` does not give that info.

Comment: Backup, format, restore :-)

Comment: Right now your question doesn't give any clue about the fact that there are files `ForDebug` and `ForDEBUG` in the same directory. Can you please edit the question to show this, so that the answer @user128998 may want to post somehow matches the problem?

Comment: There's an [answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/256935/371801) on a possible alternative to totally reformating a drive. Since it is just one file, I'd look at trying to change the software to not use such similar filenames in the same directory!

Comment: Well, those are done manually. But yes it is good practice to avoid such situations. Any command on how to get a clear error message while running rsync? That would have saved you and me a lot of trouble.

Comment: You can use a script such as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99153/119298) to list the ambiguities independently of rsync. `find . | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | LC_ALL=C sort | LC_ALL=C uniq -d`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To summarize the comments: rsync does not handle the transfer of files between a case-sensitive filesystem (typically used on Unix/Linux), and a case-insensitive filesystem (typically used by Windows and MacOS).

When 2 different source paths (eg `d/x` and `d/X`) are the same after notional conversion to, say, lowercase, then rsync does not notice, and may transfer `d/x`, then overwrite the same destination file with `d/X`. 
If the files do not contain the same data, and have the same timestamp, the files will always be updated on future rsync runs.

There does not seem to be any solution proposed by rsync. One can identify potential problems by going through the source files to [list the ambiguities](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99153/119298):

```
find . | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | LC_ALL=C sort | LC_ALL=C uniq -d
```

Alternatively, a case-sensitive destination can be [created](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/256935/371801).